# Don't understand what PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm getting a PLS-00049 (bad binding variable) when creating a stored procedure in Oracle SQL. Not sure what's wrong here:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_REGISTRATION(
    customer_id_arg IN DECIMAL,
    cus_account_id_arg IN DECIMAL,
    registration_date_arg IN DATE)
    IS
    BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM REGISTRATION
      WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
      IF CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID THEN
         INSERT INTO REGISTRATION(customer_id, cus_account_id, 
         registration_date)
         VALUES(customer_id_arg, CUS_ACCOUNT_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, CAST(SYSDATE AS 
         DATE));
      ELSE
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Customer ID does not exist. Choose an existing Customer ID in order to 
         register an extra account under an existing customer.');
     END IF;
   END;
```

These are the specific errors:
        Error(8,25): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CUSTOMER_ID'
        Error(9,22): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CUSTOMER_ID'

Comment: You appear to be confusing a trigger with a stored procedure.

Comment: What if I wanted to add a new instance with a stored procedure but check to see if the primary key value exists or not? The scenario here is that I have customers that can have multiple accounts. If I wanted to register multiple accounts under their name, I want to use a stored procedure to create the extra account. So if I'm adding a new customer_id, I want to make sure that it already exists so I can create a new account. If not, raise an error.

Comment: . . `:NEW` is a construct that only works in triggers.  I would suggest that you ask another question, provide sample data, desired results and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:NEW` and `:OLD` pseudo-rows only exist in a trigger. If you want to call a subprogram which uses data from `:NEW` or `:OLD` you can do that, but you'll have to pass each field as an argument to the procedure or function. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_REGISTRATION(customer_id_arg IN DECIMAL)
IS
  rowRegistration  REGISTRATION%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- The following SELECT will raise NO_DATA_FOUND if the passed-in CUSTOMER_ID
  -- doesn't exist, in which case we want to insert the new customer into the database.
  -- If the CUSTOMER_ID arg already exists in REGISTRATION we want to raise an
  -- application error.

  SELECT *
    INTO rowRegistration
    FROM REGISTRATION
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = customer_id_arg;

  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Customer ID does not exist. Choose an existing Customer ID in order to 
     register an extra account under an existing customer.');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO REGISTRATION(customer_id, cus_account_id, registration_date)
       VALUES(customer_id_arg, CUS_ACCOUNT_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE);
END ADD_REGISTRATION;
```

Then in your trigger you would call the above routine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REGISTRATION_VIEW_II
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON REGISTRATION_VIEW
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  REGISTRATION_ADD(:NEW.CUSTOMER_ID);
END REGISTRATION_VIEW_II;
```

(Here I'm assuming that this trigger is supposed to be an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on a view, because that's the only thing that makes sense to me without further context, but you probably have some other use case I'm unaware of).

Best of luck.